# How to call ActionResult to get Data again in MVC

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

```
public ActionResult Countries(int id=0, int from=0)
```

My Controller and the ActionResult that return Countries.

now:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Matches)
{   
    <tr>
        <td>                
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)     
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

My view, how do I say From += 10 and make the ID stay the same as the ID in the page it is open right now, and just take 10 more countries from DB?

```
@Html.ActionLink("next", "Countries", Model.From += 10)
```

This didn't work

Comment: You have to extend your model and add a hidden field in your view with Html.HiddenFor().

Comment: Can you please explain a bit better, or link me a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an inline javascript to do this.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("next", "Countries", parseInt(Model.From)+10)
```